# How to merge 3 lists into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```py
origen = ['Philadelphia', 'New Orleans']
destino = ['Atlanta', 'Dallas', 'Columbus', 'Boston']
costo = [ ['2','6','6','2'] , ['1','2','5','7'] ]
```

How I need them to be merged:

```
costo_envios={
              Philadelphia:{
                          Atlanta:2
                          Dallas:6
                          Columbus:6
                          Boston:2
                           }
              New Orleans:{
                           Atlanta:1
                           Dallas:2
                           Columbus:5
                           Boston:7             
                           }
             }
```

I thought of using maybe 2 nested 'for', but I get an "unlashable" error, which means I'm using the wrong type of index.

I also have tried this:

```py
costo_envio = {origen[l]:{destino[m]:costo[n]} for l,m,n in range(len(origen))}
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at `itertools` in the standard library?

Comment: [mre] and stacktrace. The "unhashable error" means you try to use a dict or set or list as _KEY_ - which you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 for loops, the outer one to iterate over the origins and the lists of costs, and the inner one to iterate over the destinations and the costs.

Here's my code, hope it helps!

```py
origen = ['Philadelphia', 'New Orleans']
destino = ['Atlanta', 'Dallas', 'Columbus', 'Boston']
costo = [['2', '6', '6', '2'], ['1', '2', '5', '7']]

my_dict = {}

for origin, cost_list in zip(origen, costo):
    my_dict[origin] = {}
    for dest, cost in zip(destino, cost_list):
        my_dict[origin][dest] = cost
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your desired structure and let Python dictionary comprehension work.

```py
res = {o: {d:c for d, c in zip(destino, co)} for o, co in zip(origen, costo)}
```

You can also build 2 nested for loops if you think it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the Python documentation and start studying about [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and the [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) literal syntax.

Here is one implementation, that uses the concept of [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-dict_comprehension) and the zip function:

```
costo_envio = {o: {d: int(c) for d, c in zip(destino, co)} for o, co in zip(origen, costo)}

# {'Philadelphia': {'Atlanta': 2, 'Dallas': 6, 'Columbus': 6, 'Boston': 2},
#  'New Orleans': {'Atlanta': 1, 'Dallas': 2, 'Columbus': 5, 'Boston': 7}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that a list of pairs can be turned into a dictionary.

```
d = dict(zip(origen, (dict(zip(*pairs)) for pairs in zip([destino]*len(costo), costo))))

print(d)
```